# What am I doing wrong? Querying Arxiv API

Tags: python, arxiv

I am trying to get articles from the Arxiv API based on a basic keyword search. I am using the python package "arxiv"

Here is my code:

```
import arxiv

def get_arxiv_articles(keywords):
    """Use Python arxiv package to get the top 10 articles by relevance"""
    
    client = arxiv.Client()
    search = arxiv.Search(
        query=keywords,
        max_results=10
    )

    links = []
    for r in list(client.results(search)):
        links.append(r.entry_id)

    return links
```

When I do `get_arxiv_articles("quantum computing")` it will produce the proper output once every like hour or so, then go back to returning nothing.

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. It says on the Arxiv website that the rate limit is just no more than once every three seconds, so I don't think I'm overusing the service. There is no API key needed, it is a free service.